# In Alexander Kazantsev's "Burning Island", what is the connection that Bakov saw between those things?

Tags: burning-island

In Alexander Kazantsev's "Burning Island", what is the connection that Bakov saw between those things?

> My dear, you need to see the connection between the saying of Engels, the characteristics of the explosion in the forest, and Taimba's reaction! - said Bakov.

What exactly was the connection that Bakov meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Engels said something like "if there is life developing somewhere, it will evolve into a being very much like human. Being which will embrace the nature and which will look similar to human". The forest was damaged as if explosion happened in the air, not on the surface. Taimba's reaction was as if she witnessed something special (aliens?). For Bakov, all three things were connected, were related.